# Add a column to Pandas DataFrame with multiple lookups based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column (col5) to the DataFrame such as below where the value in `col5` needs to be a value from `col4` that satisfies certain conditions in another column at the same row. For example, at row 1 in `col5`, I wanted a value from `col4` such that `col1 and col2` has a value the same as row 1 but the value in `col3` is != value in row1. In excel this can be done using sumifs as shown in the image. Any help is appreciated.
[image: Image shown in the link below]
I have updated my question based on the answer from Paul.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], "col2":['a','a','b', 'b','c', 'c', 'd', 'd'], "col3":['p','q','p', 'q', 'p','q','p', 'q'], 'col4':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800]})
```

What I want to accomplish is something like below to add a `col5` which checks conditions on other columns where `col1` and `col2` should be the same but `col3` should not match. Assuming that `col3` will have only two different values so saying `col3` to not match means `col3` should have another value.

```
df2 = df

df['col5'] = df[(df.col1 == df2.col1) & (df.col2 == df2.col2) & (df.col3 != df2.col3)].col4

df

>>>

  col1 col2 col3 col4   col5
0   1   a    p   100    NaN
1   1   a    q   200    NaN
2   1   b    p   300    NaN
3   1   b    q   400    NaN
4   2   c    p   500    NaN
5   2   c    q   600    NaN
6   2   d    p   700    NaN
7   2   d    q   800    NaN
```

When I run this I get all NaN in `col5` as shown above.

What I want to get is as below. Here the arrangement seems to make is simple like getting from the next or previous row but in the extended data, it can be at any row.

```
>>>

  col1 col2 col3 col4   col5
0   1   a    p   100    200
1   1   a    q   200    100
2   1   b    p   300    400
3   1   b    q   400    300
4   2   c    p   500    600
5   2   c    q   600    500
6   2   d    p   700    800
7   2   d    q   800    700
```

Comment: kindly share sample, reproducible data, with expected output dataframe

Comment: I shared a possible answer, not sure if it is the answer you are looking for. Please add an expected output dataframe in your question, as @sammywemmy suggested.

Comment: Sorry that I did not attach the data in reproducible format. My bad. Thanks a lot Paul for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but what I understood was:
check if col1 and col2 are the same as the next row, but col3 is different.

If so: grab the value of col4 of the next row as col5.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], "col2":['a','a','b', 'b','c', 'c', 'd', 'd'], "col3":['p','q','p', 'q', 'p','q','p', 'q'], 'col4':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800]})

df2 = df.shift(-1)
df['col5'] = df2[(df.col1 == df2.col1) & (df.col2 == df2.col2) & (df.col3 != df2.col3)].col4

df
```

```
        col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0       1       a       p       100     200.0
1       1       a       q       200     NaN
2       1       b       p       300     400.0
3       1       b       q       400     NaN
4       2       c       p       500     600.0
5       2       c       q       600     NaN
6       2       d       p       700     800.0
7       2       d       q       800     NaN
```

#### Update

If you also want the other values to be found, use `apply`:

```
df['col5'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df[
        (df.col1 == x.col1) & 
        (df.col2 == x.col2) & 
        (df.col3 != x.col3)
        ].reset_index()['col4'],
    axis=1)
```

This is a better way to iterate over you rows.

Comment: @sri If my answer is useful/helpful, don't hesitate to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for putting together the data in the correct form. I can see that my question was not very clear but the solution you have suggested gave me the idea probably that I was missing. I was not getting to how I can do something like df['col1'] = df['col1'] or df['col3'] != df['col3']. But from what I see in your answer I thought I can at least try something and explain the question in a better way. I have updated my question based on this.

Comment: @sri I updated my answer, it now suits your desired output.

Comment: Thanks this is much efficient way than my iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out how to do this. I am currently iterating over each row of the dataframe to get the job done.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  df.loc[i,'col5'] = df[(df.col1 == df.loc[i,'col1']) & (df.col2 == 
  df.loc[i,'col2']) & (df.col3 != df.loc[i,'col3'])].col4.sum()

df
>>>
 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0   1   a   p   100  200.0
1   1   a   q   200  100.0
2   1   b   p   300  400.0
3   1   b   q   400  300.0
4   2   c   p   500  600.0
5   2   c   q   600  500.0
6   2   d   p   700  800.0
7   2   d   q   800  700.0
```

I would be glad to know if there is a better and efficient way to do this without iterating. Thanks!